# Dynamic forms validations? yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

i've been playing around for a while but i can't seem to figure out what the error is or how to solve it. All i can think off is that it happens because my wbranganca dynamic forms widget doesn't know how to act when i set my custom rule to it.

My problem: I have wbranganca dynamic forms, i have some fields that do validate basic rules such as only integers allowed, or it is required and it can't be left blank, but when i add a custom rule such as no greater than, or a date rule such as no older than 5 days, it doesn't display any error when i input it into the field, but when i click on save form i receive a white screen. And the data is not saved to the table, which means that my rule works, i also try the same rule on a field outside dynamic forms and it works properly, so how can i set this the proper way?

My controller:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Archive;
use app\models\ArchiveSearch;
use app\models\Invoices;
use app\models\Model;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * ArchiveController implements the CRUD actions for Archive model.
 */
class ArchiveController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Archive models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new ArchiveSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Archive model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Archive model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Archive();
        $modelsInvoices = [new Invoices];
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load($_POST))
        {
            Yii::$app->response->format ='json';
            return \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) 
        {

            $modelsInvoices = Model::createMultiple(Invoices::classname());
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsInvoices, Yii::$app->request->post());

            /*if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ArrayHelper::merge(
                    ActiveForm::validateMultiple($modelsInvoices),
                    ActiveForm::validate($model)
                );
            }*/


            // validate all models
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsInvoices) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        foreach ($modelsInvoices as $modelInvoices)
                         {
                            $modelInvoices->archive_id = $model->id;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelInvoices->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }

        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsInvoices' => (empty($modelsInvoices)) ? [new Invoices] : $modelsInvoices
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Archive model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Archive model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Archive model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Archive the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Archive::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

My model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\Query;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "invoices".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $invoice_number
 * @property string $invoice_loadamount
 * @property string $invoice_date
 * @property integer $archive_id
 * @property string $DateProcessed
 *
 * @property Archive $archive
 */
class Invoices extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'invoices';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['invoice_number', 'invoice_loadamount', 'invoice_date'], 'required'],
            [['archive_id'], 'integer'],
            [['DateProcessed'], 'safe'],
            //Checks if invoice date put in is older than 5 days
            [['invoice_date'], 'date', 'format'=>"dd-MM-yyyy", 'min'=>date("d-m-Y",strtotime('-5 days'))],

            [['invoice_number', 'invoice_loadamount', 'invoice_date'], 'string', 'max' => 100]];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'invoice_number' => 'Invoice Number',
            'invoice_loadamount' => 'Invoice Loadamount',
            'invoice_date' => 'Invoice Date',
            'archive_id' => 'Archive ID',
            'DateProcessed' => 'Date Processed'];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getArchive()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Archive::className(), ['id' => 'archive_id']);
    }

    public function compareweight($attribute,$params)
        {
        $inputlp=($this->invoice_loadamount);
        $row = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select('vehicle_lp')
        ->from('vehicles')
        ->where("vehicle_lp=$vehiclelp")
        ->all();

        }
}
```

My view:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
use app\models\Drivers;
use app\models\Vehicles;
use app\models\Invoices;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
use yii\helpers\Url;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Archive */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="archive-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'driver_identitynum')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Drivers::find()->all(),'driver_identitynum', 'fullname'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero de cedula...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true],
    ]); ?>

        <div align="right"><?= Html::a('Add driver', ['/drivers/create'], 
       ['target'=>'_blank']); ?> 
       </div>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'vehicle_lp')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Vehicles::find()->all(),'vehicle_lp', 'fulltruck'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Ingrese la placa del vehiculo...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]); ?>

    <div align="right"><?= Html::a('Add vehicle', ['/vehicles/create'], 
       ['target'=>'_blank']); ?> 
       </div>

   <div class="row"> <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Addresses</h4></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
             <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 4, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelsInvoices[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    'invoice_number',
                    'invoice_loadamount',
                    'invoice_date',
                ],
            ]); ?>

            <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
            <?php foreach ($modelsInvoices as $i => $modelInvoices): ?>
                <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Address</h3>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (! $modelInvoices->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelInvoices, "[{$i}]id");
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelInvoices, "[{$i}]invoice_number")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelInvoices, "[{$i}]invoice_loadamount")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelInvoices, "[{$i}]invoice_date")->widget(
    DatePicker::className(), [
        // inline too, not bad
         'inline' => false, 
         // modify template for custom rendering
        //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
        'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy'
        ]
    ]);?>

                            </div>
                        </div><!-- .row -->
                        <div class="row">

                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Just Model code is enough ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**View**

Put `['enableAjaxValidation' => true]` in field.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <?= $form->field($modelInvoices, "[{$i}]invoice_date",['enableAjaxValidation' => true])->widget(
        DatePicker::className(), [
        'inline' => false, 
        'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy'
            ]
        ]);
    ?>
</div>
```

**Controller**

Add `use yii\web\Response;` & `use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;`

And, change your code structure according to the below code.

```
<?php
// These two lines are mandatory. 
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

public function actionCreate()
{
  $model = new Archive();
  $modelsInvoices = [new Invoices];

  $modelsInvoices = Model::createMultiple(Invoices::classname());
  Model::loadMultiple($modelsInvoices, Yii::$app->request->post());

  if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
  {
      Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
      return ActiveForm::validate($modelsInvoices);

  } elseif ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
      .
      .
  }
  .
  .
}
```

*It will work.*

For more info, Please click [Validating unique email using DynamicFormWidget - Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605856/validating-unique-email-using-dynamicformwidget-yii2)